# Undefined Offset multidimensional array Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I just can't get this array to play nice.
I'm using Laravel 4.2 and am throwing: ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN) Undefined offset: 1

```
$tags = Test\Zero::get_tags();

dd ($tags);

    array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      'guid' => string '-a035-4742-bb65-c44' (length=36)
      'name' => string 'tagtest1' (length=9)
      'updateSequenceNum' => int 14
      'parentGuid' => null
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      'guid' => string '-905e-466e-9e91-33ddggg4' (length=36)
      'name' => string 'testtag2' (length=11)
      'updateSequenceNum' => int 19
      'parentGuid' => null

$tags = array_dot(`$tags);


array (size=8)
  '0.guid' => string '-a035-4742-bb65-c44' (length=36)
  '0.name' => string 'tagtest1' (length=9)
  '0.updateSequenceNum' => int 14
  '0.parentGuid' => null
  '1.guid' => string '-905e-466e-9e91-33ddggg4' (length=36)
  '1.name' => string 'testtag2' (length=11)
  '1.updateSequenceNum' => int 19
  '1.parentGuid' => null


$name = array_fetch($tags, '1.name');
echo $name;
```

How can I loop through to display all values with key 'name' ? 
Everything I try gives ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN) Undefined offset:

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A simple loop like `foreach ($tags as $tag) { echo $tag['name']; }` will do - if you have PHP5.5, you can also use `$names = array_column($tags, 'name');` to retrieve an array of all the names http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: How bizarre - thought had tried that - it works - Thankyou!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While @MichaelBerkowski is correct, if you did want to do this with Laravel array helpers, it would be:

```
$names = array_fetch($tags, 'name');
```

which would give you an array, not a string (so having `echo $name` like in your example would give you an `Array to string conversion` error).

You may be confusing the syntax you were attempting for when you have a multidimensional associate array as in the Laravel docs for array_fetch: http://laravel.com/docs/helpers

Incidentally, if `$tags` was a Collection, you could do: `$tags->lists('name');`

Comment: Yes I did initially get the array to string error - the collections class looks useful - thanks for advice